# cannot build OpenglES2.0 sample from android sdk

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, adt

I'm new to android development, just installed android SDK.
When I add a BasicGLSurfaceViewActivity sample to workspace, IDE shows a lot of errors like these ones:

- GLES20 cannot be resolved    GLES20TriangleRenderer.java
- The import android.opengl.GLES20 cannot be resolved  BasicGLSurfaceView.java

Target SDK version from project manifest is 11.

I took this sample from sdk/samples/andriod-17.

I installed in SDK manager all packages related to both API-11 and API-17.

Existence of GLES20 sample in SDK should mean that GLES20 is supported, shouldn't it?
What may went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found solution: change "target" variable in project.properties file to be more than 7.
Android documentation says:
"Beginning with Android 2.2 (API Level 8), the framework supports the OpenGL ES 2.0 API specification."

Comment: Does anybody know, what ADT IDE is guided by when in set this variable on project creation?

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me with the same problem! I`ve changed it to android-8 and it compiled.